# Cannot write German characters scraped from XPath to CSV file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, utf-8, data-cleaning

I am trying to write information containing German umlaut characters into a CSV. When I write only the first parameter, "name", it comes out correctly. If I write "name" and "institution" though, I get this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 71: character maps to <undefined>`

As you can see in the code below, I tried encoding and decoding the text using different combinations of characters.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# this is the header of the csv
with open('/filepath/result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write("name, institution, \n")

l = list(range(1148, 1153))

for i in l:
    url = 'webaddress.com' + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@style="width:600px; display:inline-block;"]')[0].text
    name = '\"' + name + '\"'
    institution = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@style="width:600px; display:inline-block;"]')[1].text
    institution = '\"' + institution + '\"'
    print(str(i) + ': ' + name, '\n', str(i) + ': ' + institution, '\n')
    print(institution.encode('utf-8'))
    print(institution.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
    print(institution.encode('utf-8').decode('ISO-8859-15'))
    with open('/filepath/result.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(name + ',' + institution + '\n')

driver.close()
```

The results that show up in the CSV when I set all encodings to UTF-8 look like the one where I encode UTF-8 and decode ISO-8859-15 (latin1). I got the same error as above when I encoded latin1 and decoded utf-8.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line at the top of your `foo.py` file as:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

As an alternative you can use the `io` module as follows:

```
import io

# this is the header of the csv
with io.open('/filepath/result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write("name, institution, \n")
```

and later:

```
with io.open('/filepath/result.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write((name + ',' + institution + '\n')..encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: This didn't work. It wrote to the CSV but not correctly.

Comment: @JustinBurack Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Adding .encode("utf-8") to the f.write line showed an error: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the purpose of `encode`.  Why would you `print(institution.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))`; this is simply equivalent to `print(institution)`!

I'm guessing your traceback comes from one of the `print`s rather than the `write()`.  Try taking out the offending one(s); or simply figure out how to print Unicode to your console and then just do that.

Probably read Ned Batchelder's [Pragmatic Unicode.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)